# Velleman's exercise $3.1.7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

> Prove that if $a^3>a$ then $a^5>a$.

Velleman gives this "hint":

$$\text{One approach is to start by completing the following equation:}\ (a^5-a)=(a^3-a) \cdot x$$

I don't understand this hint. Can someone please explain the hint and do the proof using this hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given inequality is equivalent to $a^3-a=a(a^2-1)>0$. By multiplying both sides by $a^2+1$, which is always positive, we get $a(a^2-1)(a^2+1)>a^2+1>0$, or $a^5-a>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Factorizing both $a^5-a$ and $a^3-a$ gives
$$a^5-a=a(a^4-1)=a(a^2+1)(a^2-1)=a(a^2+1)(a-1)(a+1)$$
$$a^3-a=a(a^2-1)=a(a-1)(a+1).$$
So, we know that the $x$ in 
$$a^5-a=(a^3-a)x$$
has to be $a^2+1$. Then, we have
$$a^5-a=(a^3-a)(a^2+1).$$
Here, note that $a^2+1$ is positive for every $a\in\mathbb R$.